# Datatype of column gets changed after accessing it

Tags: pandas, dataframe

One of column values contains list of list, Please refer following snapshot of dataframe for reference

[image: Pandas Dataframe with list of list]

When trying to get the stitched_token column values it gets converted into string instead of list of list. I need the column value as type of list of list instead of the string.

Currently accessing the values like:

```
df['stitched_token'][0]
```

Which return following type of values

[image]

Comment: `data = '[[161, 1421, 181, 1456]]'`，Convert to list via `eval(data)`